# LDAP's user authentication test in linux scripting

Tags: authentication, ldap

I want to use LDAP user's credential in one of my Linux scripts, in which I want to take user name and password and want to test the authentication.

I have used `ldapsearch` command to check the user's name validation and now want to check the same for the password.

Is there any command I can use to check this?

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, are you looking to take a username and password as input from the user in your script and test them against an LDAP server? If that's the case, you could try authenticating against the LDAP server with the username/password and just see if it works.

Comment: yes, you are right. So is it achievable through "ldapsearch" command?

Comment: Yes, you can pass the username and password using parameters to the ldapsearch command and if it fails that would be one way to know the credentials are incorrect.

Comment: Thnx Dan, but I am not familiar with LDAP. Can you please brief me more. I am using the below command to use user validation.
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.global.css.com/ -b 
'ou=netgroup,dc=gds,o=css.com' cn=cssgrp | grep "rajat"

Comment: So how can I use this command to test the credentials? Here "rajat" is a user name that is the member of "cssgrp" net group. Please suggest...

Comment: the -D option takes the DN for logging in to your LDAP server. Put the user info in the value for -D. The -b option takes the search base in your LDAP tree where you want to search for the user's given name. Use the -w option for your password